# Is accessing Generic Objects bad compared to Strict Data-Type classes in AS3?

Tags: performance, actionscript-3, flash, memory

I'm having a debate with a friend regarding **Generic Objects** vs. **Strict Data-Type instances** access.

If I have a fairly large **JSON** file to convert to objects & arrays of data in Flash, is it best that I then convert those objects to strict AS3 classes dedicated to each objects?

Is there a significant loss on performance depending on the quantity of objects?

What's the technical reason behind this? Does Generic Object leave a bigger foot-print in memory than Strict Data-Type instances of a custom class?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to answer this question on a generic scale since in the end "it all depends". What it depends on is what type of objects you are working with, how you expose those objects to the rest of the program and what type of requirements you have on your runtime environment.

Generally speaking, generic objects are bad since you no longer have "type security".
Generally speaking, converting objects to typed objects forces you to leave a bigger memory footprint since you need to run that class during runtime, and also forces you to recompile an untyped object "again" into another type of object, causing some extra cpu cycles.

In the end it kinda bowls down to this, if the data that you received is exposed to the rest of system, it's generally a good idea to convert it into some kind of typed object.

Converting it to a typed object and then working on that object, improves code readability and makes it easier to read the code since you don't have to remember if the data/key table used "image" or "Image" or "MapImage" as the accessor to retrieve the image info of something.

Also, if you ever change the backend system to provide other/renamed keys, you only have to do the change in one place, instead of scattered all over the system.

Hope this answer helps :)

Comment: Every class/code line/character you add to your sollution, "pollutes" the application with extra information (thus improves it's size and memory footprint). Every object you receive into flash takes cpu and memory to create. Converting from the allready created object into another object takes both extra memory and cpu cycles. But, unless you are working inside a very, VERY restricted field this will not be an issue and thus "easier to read code" is almost ALWAYS preferred. Otherwise you wouldn't be using ActionScript in the first place :)